# Java/JSP multidimensional array declaration whose size is known later

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, multidimensional-array

I have a piece of code where in I create a multidimensional array inside an if condition using a return of a function, but the value of the array is needed outside the if statement...

```
// Need to declare/initialize array here
if(some condition){
    String csvdata[][] = ParseCSV.CSVTextToArray(file);
}
// Need to use csvdata[][] here
```

How can I do this!
Ideally would like to initilize/declare csvdata[][] before the if, but will not mind another variable, as long as I don't need a loop to store the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write as

```
String csvdata[][]= null;
        if(Some Condition)
        {
            csvdata = ParseCSV.CSVTextToArray(file);
        }
        System.out.println(csvdata[0][0]);
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks! I was trying 'csvdata[][] = ParseCSV.CSVTextToArray(file);', hence it was not working.